# call crm web service from outlook add-in

Tags: javascript, web-services, authentication, crm, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an add-in for outlook in O365 and need to get and update info in crm online. Ideal would be to do this call from the web app where the add-in is hosted but I'm trying to avoid it because of customer requirements. What I'm trying to do is call crm online from the the javascript code from the add-in.
I would need to get the ADFS token got when logged into outlook and use it to call crm online from the addin. Is that possible? How do I get the token? Is it possible to call crm online using the Crm Web API or how should i do it? How do I avoid cross side scripting errors as I would be calling from outside the server?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to dev.office.com, cross-domain requests are blocked due to same-origin policy:

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations

You'll need to set up a backend server to relay cross-domain requests or use CORS if it's available on the CRM api you are using.